# SSO login based on OAuth2 AccessTokenProvider

Tags: spring, oauth

My application login is externalized into an external form based on OAuth2 Authorization Code Flow.

I wonder how to solve the problem explained in the [Spring IO forum](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/oauth/121682-authentication-is-required-to-obtain-an-access-token-anonymous-not-allowed) taking into account that AccessTokenProvider (`org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain`) will always complain by an Anonymous user (obviously physical customer is trying to authenticate and no authentication object is set yet):

```
if (auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) {
    if (!resource.isClientOnly()) {
        throw new InsufficientAuthenticationException(
            "Authentication is required to obtain an access token (anonymous not allowed)");
    }
}
```

Comment: I respond myself, may be injecting an org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider directly instead of falling back to defaults (org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain) is the easiest solution in my case

Comment: If you found your own answer, consider writing an answer using the buttons below. It will help readers in the future find the problem you had faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I respond to myself, it looks like injecting an org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.‌​AuthorizationCodeAcc‌​essTokenProvider directly instead of falling back to defaults (org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessToke‌​nProviderChain) is the easiest solution in my case